# R Shiny - Passing User Input as Global String

Tags: r, shiny, render, reactive

How do I take in a user input and store as environment string in server.R?

Here's an example (which produces an error):

```
library(shiny)

# Define the UI

n <- 100

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  textOutput('count_new')
)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {

  count <- as.numeric(renderText({input$n}))
  output$count_new <- renderText({count/10})

}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Key is to use `reactive` in front of input. The variable can then be called followed by `()`.

```
library(shiny)

# Define the UI

n <- 100

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  textOutput('count_new')
)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {

  count <- reactive({input$n})
  output$count_new <- renderText({count()/10})

}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```